# How to make a GPS foreground service which not being stopped when phone screen is turned off?

Tags: java, android, foreground-service

I'm trying to make a foreground service that will track the user running path

I want to this server run and track user location until the user closed  but now it works fine with location tracking and path but the only problem is that when I service and put phone in pocket then after some time the service is being destroyed. but i put it on table then service  run all over the night

Here is the code for starting the 
`java startForegroundService(new Intent(this, GoogleService.class));`

Here is the code for the timer which starts when service is being started

````
        mTimer.schedule(new TimerTaskToGetLocation(), 10,1000 );```

in TimerTasktoGetLocation 
```java                         sendNotification_pause(getString(R.string.app_name)+" mp service",utils.convertSecondsToHMmSs(total_time),distance);
````

This the code for showing notification

```java
RemoteViews notificationLayout = null;

        notificationLayout= new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification_location);


        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GoogleService.class);
        PendingIntent pendIntentapp_oopen = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(context, DrawerActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT), 0);
        PendingIntent pending_intent_end = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent.setAction(Actions.SERVICE_STOP), 0);

       notificationLayout.setTextViewText(R.id.custom_notification_distance, "Distanz: "+Utils.distance_with_unite(distance));
        notificationLayout.setTextViewText(R.id.custom_notification_duration, "Dauer: "+duration);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "CANNEL01")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.login_logo)
                .setAutoCancel(false)
                .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
                .setCustomContentView(notificationLayout)
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                .addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action(R.drawable.ic_close_black_24dp,"End",pending_intent_end))
                .setContentIntent(pendIntentapp_oopen);


        builder.setOngoing(true);


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
            @SuppressLint("WrongConstant") NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("CANNEL01", "Location", importance);
            channel.setDescription("All the different interval tones");
            // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
            // or other notification behaviors after this
            NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            startForeground(101,builder.build());


        }else {
            startForeground(101,builder.build());

            NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        }
```

I want to this server run and track user location until the user closed  but now it works fine with location tracking and path but the only problem is that when I service and put phone in pocket then after some time the service is being destroyed. one more thing when i keep it on a table then service runs all over the night.
I'm wondering how why this happens

for an example  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.runtastic.android&hl=en
this app does not request any special permission and track the path, it will be also a good i get a clue how this kind of service works ?

Comment: Thank for commenting, i have tested this methods, but when i start the service and put phone in pocket and start driving then it kill the service, so this is not explained in the mentioned question

Comment: Ah I see; you have a working foreground service. I wonder, how exactly are you determining that the Service is being destroyed? The notification goes away? Also, when it runs all night, does it happen to be charging?

Comment: Yes, the notification is go away, one more thing i want to tell, im clearing all the notifications in the onDestroy function of the service,

Comment: I have noticed one thing that, the notification update stoped, because when i unlocked the phone notification not updates but after some it again start updating, i have used timer for continuously update the notification which show time duration from start of the service

Comment: And the charging?

Comment: No the phone is not charging,

Comment: I can share the full service class code through GitHub if you need ,

Comment: So a `Service` will either crash, or end when you tell it to. `onDestroy()` will only be called if you've issued commands to end the service in an orderly way. On the other hand, if it crashes, there will be something in logcat. It sounds like your code may be crashing b/c the GPS position is changing.

Comment: Can you see through the service file ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201139/discussion-between-greeble31-and-vicky-khan).